# C threads giving garbage output when accessing non-shared resource

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I am learning how to use threads in C, and am trying to use a worker function (one with a '`void* helperFunc(void *arg)`' signature) to call a regular function and pass it the address of an integer in an array.

Sometimes, the output will be correct (a list of zeroes). Other times, there will be garbage values instead of 0.

None of the threads are trying to access shared resources, and I believe I have intialised the array correctly, so I don't understand where the garbage values are coming from.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define N 10

void runMe(int *arg) {
    printf("Hello %d\n", *arg);
}

void *helperFunc(void *arg){
    runMe((int*)arg);
}

int run_threads(void){
    pthread_t thread[N];
    int num[N] = {0};

    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++){
        pthread_create(&(thread[i]), NULL, helperFunc, &(num[i]));
    }
}

int main(){
    run_threads();
    sleep(1);
    return 0;
}
```

Expected output:

```
Hello 0  
Hello 0  
Hello 0  
Hello 0  
Hello 0  
Hello 0  
Hello 0  
Hello 0  
Hello 0  
Hello 0
```

Actual output:

```
Hello 0  
Hello 0  
Hello 0  
Hello 0  
Hello 0  
Hello 0  
Hello 32757  
Hello 4195339  
Hello 0  
Hello -334463544
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You are passing threads the address of an object that is not guaranteed to exist when they access it. As soon as `run_threads` returns, `num` no longer exists.

Comment: Thanks. I have corrected the problem by using malloc to allocate space for the integers.

Comment: @ChrisJolly: If you're going to do anything useful with the array, you'll need to think about returning it so it can be freed, and worry about how you're going to wait for the threads to exit (`sleep(1)` is clumsy — `pthread_join()`?), etc.  Maybe that's for the future; getting it working cleanly is a start.

Comment: Thanks. I have returned to using an array of ints, with pthread_join to allow them all to finish executing before run_threads returns.

Comment: A common pattern is to call `malloc` before creating the thread and then have the thread call `free` when it's done with its parameters.